# When constructing a new property with a Calculated Property, how to cast a string to [datetime] object?

Tags: powershell

```
[
    {
    "Title":"stackoverflow",
    "URL":"https://stackoverflow.com",
    "Modified Time":""
    }
    ,
    {
    "Title":"example",
    "URL":"https://example.com",
    "Modified Time": "11/01/2022 14:38:48"
    }
    ,
    {
    "Title":"reddit",
    "URL":"https://reddit.com",
    "Modified Time": "11/01/2023 14:38:48"
    }
    ,
    {
    "Title":"bbc",
    "URL":"https://bbc.com",
    "Modified Time": "01/11/2024 09:00:00"
    }
]
```

I have a json file like the above.

I need to do two things to it:

- Rename the property `Modified Time` to `CreationTime`
- and then sort the object by `CreationTime` in either Ascending or Descending

I have managed to rename the property but I am failing to sort the the object by the `CretionTime` property. `CreationTime` is a string,  `sort-object` does not do a good job of sorting by `CreationTime` sequentially.

`sort-object CreationTime` gives me:

```
Title         URL                       CreationTime
-----         ---                       ------------
stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com
bbc           https://bbc.com           01/11/2024 09:00:00
example       https://example.com           11/01/2022 14:38:48
reddit        https://reddit.com        11/01/2023 14:38:48
```

and `sort creationtime -Descending`

```
Title         URL                       CreationTime
-----         ---                       ------------
reddit        https://reddit.com        11/01/2023 14:38:48
example       https://example.com           11/01/2022 14:38:48
bbc           https://bbc.com           01/11/2024 09:00:00
stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com
```

You can see in both cases, the date is not sorted sequentially.

I Am thinking if I cast  the string `CreationTime` to a `[datetime]` object, then maybe  `sort-object` will be able to sort it properly.

The issue I am having is that sometimes a object does not have a date, in the above sample, the first object's property `modified time` has no value. So to avoid getting the error `InvalidArgument: Cannot convert value..."`, inside the calculated property, I need to check if `modified time` is blank or not. I tried:

```
Get-Content -path "/path/to/json.json" | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object *, @{name = 'CreationTime' ; Expression = [datetime](("Modified Time").Length -eq 0 ? '01/01/2000' : "Modified Time")} | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty "Modified Time" |Sort-Object -Property CreationTime
```

I get the error:

```
InvalidArgument: Cannot convert value "Modified Time" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "The string 'Modified Time' was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index '0'."
```

I am essentially trying to do the following:

```
$date = "05/12/2024"    #  or ---> $date = ""
[datetime]($date.Length -eq 0 ? '01/01/2000' : $date)
```

I am wondering, inside a Calculated Property block, how do I refer to the current object and its property?

PS: I am using `...Select-Object *, @{name = 'Creat...` because this object has a variable list of properties. Also `...Select-Object -ExcludeProperty "Modified Time"...` is just to omit `Modified Time` from the new object.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some typos in your `Expression` argument, first of all, it has to be either a [ScriptBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.4) or the name of a property so, `Expression = { .... }` or `Expression = 'PropertyName'`, see [**about Calculated Properties**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.3#select-object) for more info.

Then the other typo is that you're not referencing the current object in pipeline ([`$_`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_psitem?view=powershell-7.4)).

In summary, your expression should be:

```
Expression = { [datetime](($_.'Modified Time').Length -eq 0 ? '01/01/2000' : $_.'Modified Time') }
```

And the full code:

```bash
Get-Content -Path .\test.json -Raw |
    ConvertFrom-Json |
    Select-Object *, @{ Name = 'CreationTime' ; Expression = { [datetime](($_.'Modified Time').Length -eq 0 ? '01/01/2000' : $_.'Modified Time') }} -ExcludeProperty 'Modified Time' |
    Sort-Object -Property CreationTime

# Title         URL                       CreationTime
# -----         ---                       ------------
# stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com 1/1/2000 12:00:00 AM
# example       https://example.com       11/1/2022 2:38:48 PM
# reddit        https://reddit.com        11/1/2023 2:38:48 PM
# bbc           https://bbc.com           1/11/2024 9:00:00 AM
```

Comment: This is amazing, thank you for sure, I will get to reading those links.